# how to get return value from background thread in GUI thread c#

Tags: c#-3.0, c#-2.0

```
try
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            result = myclass.Start(mode, Check, Tasks,exeMode);
        }
        catch (GeneralException ge)
        {

        }

        finally
        {
            if (Master)
            {

            }
        }
    });
    t.IsBackground = true;
    t.Start();
    bResult = true;
}
catch(GeneralException ge)
{

}

mode = Mode.Continue;


if (ErrorCode != 0)
{                       
     this.Invoke(new System.EventHandler(_showErrorMsg), execErrorCode, EventArgs.Empty);
}
else if (result == Result.RegainRequest)
{                       
    this.Invoke(new System.EventHandler(_showMsg), Modes.RegainRequest, new EventArgs());
}
else if (result == Result.RegainRequestNoClear)
{
    this.Invoke(new System.EventHandler(_showMsg), Modes.RegainRequestNoClear, new EventArgs());
}
else if (result == Result.PathRemain)
{                        
    this.Invoke(new System.EventHandler(_showMsg), Modes.PathRemain, new EventArgs());
}
else
{
    _regainmode = RegainMode.Continue;
}
```

Here we have thread called t which is background thread. in which I have called Start method which return value as shown in above code.

I have to use this result in my GUI thread which is in below code

```
else if (result == Result.RegainRequest)
{                        
    this.Invoke(new System.EventHandler(_showMsg), Modes.RegainRequest, new EventArgs());
}
```

Please tell me how can I do this so that I can use this value in my GUI thread.

Comment: Don't use a manual thread.  Instead, use a BackgroundWorker() control which will allow you to set `e.Result` in the DoWork() handler.  The result can be obtained in the RunWorkerCompleted() event where it will be safe to update the GUI, thus also removing the need to manually use Invoke().

Comment: I have two scenario: 1) In first case I don't have to wait for completion of start method, It should run only 2) In second case I have to wait for completion of start method and use it's return value in GUI thread. That's why I have run start method on background thread. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm using Compact framework 3.0 for smart device

Comment: In that case, wrap your thread in a custom class that raises a custom event.

Comment: Problem is solved now. I have declared thread on method scope and declare result variable as static. Just checking to on that result and joing the background thread to UI thread and it's worked.